# How do I check the connection timeout in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I need to check Oracle 12c timeout for an active connection. I don't have access to the database itself but I do have some creds. Is there a table to query to get this information?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "timeout for an active connection"? Are you referring to `CONNECT_TIME` in the resource profile? something else?

Comment: @mustaccio I don't know how to name properly in Oracle database terms but I mean how long I can keep a connection open using it

Answer (score 3):

These are properties of user profiles. Query [DBA_PROFILES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DBA_PROFILES.html).

[CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-PROFILE.html)

> *resource_parameters*
>
> ...
>
> **CONNECT_TIME**
>
> Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in
>   minutes.
>
> **IDLE_TIME**
>
> Specify the permitted periods of continuous inactive time during a
>   session, expressed in minutes. Long-running queries and other
>   operations are not subject to this limit.
>
> ...

Comment: thank you for the answer! I've tried it using `SELECT CONNECT_TIME FROM SCHEMA_NAME.DBA_PROFILES;` but it gives me `ORA-00942: table or view doesn't exist`

Comment: `SYS` owns `DBA_PROFILES`.  Their is also a public synonym for it.  If you can't see it, then you don't have the proper "creds".  Your DBA should be able to help if you don't have the proper credentials

Comment: @Balazs Papp makes sense. but what are the public synonyms may be?